# Bash counting letters in string, output always a little different

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep, wc

I have a little problem with my script.
My program receives a string from the user and adds it together to make one large string in a loop that will only end if user types asterisk (`*`) somewhere in the code. Later on that code counts letters, numbers and non alpha numeric characters separately. It uses a combination of `grep [0-9] | wc`. However outputs always gets a little crazy, I give a couple of string examples.

- `.*` = 0 numbers 7 letters 0 special
- `a1` = 2 number 2 letters = 0 special
- `abc123*` = 4 numbers 4 letters 0 special
- `abc123...*` = 4 numbers 4 letters 4 special
- `.....*****` = 0 numbers = letters 6 special

In other words, it tries to add one (I assumed it might be related to the use of asterisk, but I couldn't have dealt with it), but when I only type asterisk, it comes out with crazy stuff.

```
echo $completestring | grep -o "[0-9]*" | wc -c
echo $completestring | grep -o "[a-zA-Z]*" | wc -c
echo $completestring | grep -o "[,._+:@%/-]*" | wc -c
$completestring contains a string written by the user
```

Comment: you want it to say a1 = 1 letter 1 number and 0 special?

Comment: the extra count is related to new line being counted because you're using `-c` for `wc`  also if you match `[0-9]*` matches `""`

Answer (score 2):

## Asterisk

The asterisk (`*`) matches the preceding character or a group *zero* or more times. Thus

- `[0-9]*` matches anything, i.e. a digit *zero* or more times;
- `[a-zA-Z]*` matches anything, i.e. a character from the range *zero* or more times.

If you want to match a prefix plus zero or more characters, use `.*` expression, e.g.:

- `[0-9].*`;
- `[a-zA-Z].*`.

The dot (`.`) matches a single character.

---

Some tests:

```
$ echo 'test' | grep '[0-9].*'; echo $?
1
$ echo 'test' | grep '[0-9]*'; echo $?
test
0
```

The exit status (`$?`) is 0, if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected.

## Quoting

Also note, you should enclose the shell variables in double quotes, if you want to prevent reinterpretation of the special characters: `"$myvar"`.

## Counting the number of pattern matches

Grep's `-o` option prints only the matched non-empty parts of a matching line, with each such part *on a separate line*. Thus the count of matching parts equals to the number of lines in the output. So you need `wc -l` instead:

```
$ echo 'abc123' | grep -o '[a-z]' | wc -l 
3

$ echo 'abc123def' | grep -o '[a-z]\+' 
abc
def
```

Comment: I don't think your reply answers the OP question

Comment: @AhmedMasud, why?

Comment: I might get it wrong, but your solution shows whenever or not grep finds something in a string. I try to count it all, for example: if I have string "aabbcc123123....*" Then I'd expect my code to say: 6 letters, 6 numbers, 5 special (including asterix)

Comment: @jakubek278, your question is "why you are getting "crazy" results", right? So I have described why.

Comment: You are right, I haven't even realized that I haven't stated my question correctly, sorry. my bad.

Comment: @sorontar, that's why I have mentioned quoting in the answer

Comment: Sorry, comment in wrong answer. In any case, maybe `${a//[^0-9]}` could be used.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count number of instances of particular type of characters you can do the following:

```
echo $completestring | grep -o "[0-9]" | wc -l
echo $completestring | grep -o "[a-zA-Z]" | wc -l
echo $completestring | grep -o "[,._+:@%/-]" | wc -l
```

This will for example give you the following output for the given complete string:

completestring="foo@a321abcdr%20:/mango/25b"

```
echo $completestring | grep -o "[0-9]" | wc -l
7
```

grep matches: `3` `2` `1` `2` `0` `2` `5`

```
echo $completestring | grep -o "[a-zA-Z]" | wc -l
15
```

grep matches: `f` `o` `o` `a` `a` `b` `c` `d` `r` `m` `a` `n` `g` `o` `b`

```
echo $completestring | grep -o "[,._+:@%/-]" | wc -l
5
```

grep matches: `@` `%` `:` `/` `/`

If you want to count clusters of numbers and words as a single instance (e.g. mango should be 1 not 5 and 321 should be counted as 1 number not 3) then you can use something like:

```
echo $completestring | grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*" | wc -l
echo $completestring | grep -o "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*" | wc -l
```

I think the special character count is on a per character basis.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For some reason I thought wc -l  was a way to count how many lines are in the file. I also didn't understood the asterisk in grep but I was scared to delete it because without it wc -c was giving even weirder results.

Comment: Doing echo .* (unquoted, maybe you are using zsh) may also be a source of problems. Using bash internal expansion `${a//[^a-z]}` may be faster (and simpler).

Comment: The `*` in a regular expression has nothing to do with an `*` in the *haystack* you're searching. So your input string *can* have an `*` and you can actually `grep` for it. e.g. `echo $completestring | grep '\*'`. The single quotes are "shell" specific, and the backslash (\\) is passed on to grep, so that it will skip over the _special meaning_ of a `*`

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your idea.

First, Please, please, by all means: **quote** your variable expansions.

1. Quote
   This is what happens here in some directory:

   ```
   $ completestring=.*    ;   echo $completestring
   . .. .directory .#screenon
   ```

   Instead, I believe you want:

   $ completestring=.*        ; echo "$completestring"
   .*
2. Using wc will count bytes, not characters (close to UNICODE code points). Example (in a console set for utf-8, almost all nowadays):

   ```
   $ echo "école" | wc -c 
   7

   $ echo "ß" | wc -c
   3
   ```
3. Also, wc is counting the trailing new line.

   ```
   $ echo "123" | wc -c
   4
   ```

   You need to use `echo -n` (non-portable, not recommended) or `printf '%s'`

   ```
   $ printf '%s' "123" | wc -c
   3
   ```
4. Using an asterisk with grep makes it print runs of characters in each line:

   ```
   $ completestring="jkfdsnlal92845t02u74ijopzidjb jd"

   $ echo $completestring | grep -o [0-9]*
   92845
   02
   74
   ```

   There is no simple way to count that. A simplification is to use just the range:

   ```
   $ echo $completestring | grep -o [0-9]
   9
   2
   8
   4
   5
   0
   2
   7
   4
   ```

   And then you can count lines:

   ```
   $ echo $completestring | grep -o [0-9] | wc -l
   9
   ```

   Note: I'll use only a as variable from here on.
      Is easier to type, hope you understand :).

   ```
   echo $completestring | grep -o [0-9]*
   ```
5. You should avoid including the `*` asterisk in the string under test if that is used for the end of the input. Depending on how you are reading the variable, maybe you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to signal an `EOF` to the system to end reading input from the user.

#### Using full bash:

But we can do all what we need with simple bash constructs:

```
$ a="jkfdsnlal92845t02u74ijopzidjb jd"
$ b="${#a//[^0-9]}"                       # remove all characters 
                                          # that are not decimal digits

$ echo "${b}"                             # Not really needed, but this  
928450274                                 # what var b contains.

$ echo "${#b}"                            # Print the length of var b.
9
```

What you wrote in your code could be translated to this (the `/` needs to be quoted as `\/` and I included the `*` in the special list).

```
completestring=abc123*
dig=${completestring//[^0-9]}; dig=${#dig}
alpha=${completestring//[^a-zA-Z]}; alpha=${#alpha}
special=${completestring//[^,._+:@%\/*-]}; special=${#special}
echo "Digits=$dig  Alpha=$alpha  Special=$special"
```

Will print

```
Digits=3  Alpha=3  Special=1
```

#### LC_COLLATE

There is a gotcha with this system, however.
It will count many UNICODE characters as well:

```
$ c=aßbéc123*; a=${c//[^a-zA-Z]}; echo "string=$a    count=${#a}"
string=aßbéc    count=5
```

I believe that this is what you need.

But if you must limit to the 128 ascii characters, change LC_ALL or more specifically LC_COLLATE to the C locale when executing the range selection:

```
$ (LCcompletestring=abc123*; alpha=${completestring//[^a-zA-Z]}; alpha=${#alpha}; echo "${alpha}"_COLLATE=C a=${c//[^a-zA-Z]}; echo "string=$a    count=${#a}")
string=abc    count=3
```

The (…) is to use a sub-shell and avoid setting LC_COLLATE in the whole shell.
However you may set it at the start of your script and it will also work.

This got long, sorry. But anyuway: Am I missing something still?

Well, yes, I hope your passwords will not be including control characters (C0: ASCII from 1 to 31 and 127, and C1: 128 to 159). Because counting them has several twists. Probably outside of this answer.